# Android XML layout change on rotation not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

### Issue

XML Layout change on rotation of my device.

The Layout changes if I rotate to landscape mode but if I want to rotate to portrait it loads the Landscape mode again.

---

### Things I tried

I tried to solve this issue by adding the
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">`
in the manifest but this didn't solved my problem.

I tried to recreate the landscape version of the XML layout but again no effect on the problem.

---

### XML and Manifest

Manifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.neuroinit">
    
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Potrait

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".angle.AngleFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="angleViewModel"
            type="com.example.neuroinit.angle.AngleViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/angleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mapview_of_countingpoint"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            app:countingImage="@{angleViewModel.counting}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.neuroinit.angle.LineView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/clicked_angle_0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/angleView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapImageView"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/angleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Landscape

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".angle.AngleFragment">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="angleViewModel"
            type="com.example.neuroinit.angle.AngleViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/angleLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapImageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mapview_of_countingpoint"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            app:countingImage="@{angleViewModel.counting}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/angleView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.example.neuroinit.angle.LineView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/clicked_angle_0"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/angleView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mapImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/angleView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
         app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mapImageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

A bit messy I know ;D

---

### Sidenote

The strange thing is I have another fragment with portrait and landscape XML and there it works like a charm.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it's better to share your XML layout and manifest file.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried without any `configChanges` flags set? These really shouldn't be used unless you have a very specific reason, it talks more about why here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange.

Comment: Yes I dont used the flags at the beginning. I just read that this flag may help. I deleted it after it does not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea about your problem. Try these and let me know the result.

- First option

```kotlin
onCreate(){
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
}

onPause(){ 
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
  }
}

onResume(){
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
  }
}
```

- Second option

Override the `onBackPressed()` method of Landscape activity and set orientation to Portrait.

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Comment: I tryed the first option but it dont worked for me. Still not changing the Layout from the rotation.
And the secon option I dont understand how this would solve the rotation problem D: